# Unable to use Idea - it's blanked

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I have installed Jetbrains Idea 10.5.2 to use it's great capabilities for scala programming, but I'm getting stuck with it -- it is covered with small black squares instead of characters in all menus and messages: [image: idea strange bug]

I've googled it a lot but unfortunately couldn't find anything. Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: I'd think that locating the configuration settings file, removing it (renaming it) and trying again could be effective. Otherwise, repair from installer. BTW, what distribution _are you_ using <whistle/>?

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try to change font for IDEA.
For you it could be probably hard - but you can try. Open global setting with Ctrl+Alt+S.
And then try to blindly find font option like on this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]